# Overloading stream operators (`>>` and `<<`)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload `<<` and `>>` operators in my `Array` class. I do it this way:

```cpp
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Array<T>& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.m_size; i++) {
        out << a.m_data[i] << " ";
    }
    out << endl;

    return out;
}

template<class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Array<T>& a)
{
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    in >> a.m_size;
    a.m_data = new T[a.m_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.m_size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a[" << i << "] = ";
        in >> a.m_data[i];
    }
    return in;
}
```

Is my implementation right? My `main()` didn't run when I call `cout << array` or `cin >> array`

This is class `Array`:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Array {
    private:
        int m_size;
        T* m_data;
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Array<T>& a);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Array<T>& a);
};
```

My `main()` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Array<int> b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << b;
}
```

Error message:

```
Error:LNK2019
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Array<int> &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$Array@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve], details do matter. Did you maybe but the template in a source file?

Comment: One the one hand, stop with `using namespace std;`. On the other, iterators are much preferred for container-type classes. Did you include `<iostream>`? Is your class really just what you posted? If so, it's no wonder it breaks. You can immediately go into undefined behavior by manipulating memory you don't own. The expectation that your object is invalid until you invoke the `operator>>()` is bad practice. It's worth learning about the invariant. Echoing @idclev463035818, please post a [mre]. Otherwise you're going lead everyone on a different goose chase due to the missing details.

Comment: The `operator>>` is not supposed to interact with the user in any way. Imagine reading a thousand of these from a file and having to look at all those prompts scroll by.